# Fetch jsonb column of postgres db

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

I am using `node-postgres` to select and insert data into `postgres`. I have some column of `jsonb` type which I am fetching from db by using below query

```
getEmployee() {
 return SELECT empId, empData FROM employee WHERE empId = $1;
}
```

where `empData` is `jsonb` type of column. Below is code snippet which use above query.

```
const employee = await DBService.query(pgObj.getEmployee(), [empId]);
```

when I am trying to get `empData` from `employee` I am getting empty value.

```
 const { empData } = employee;
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. Is this the correct way to fetch `josnb` column of `postgreas` db in `nodejs`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `empdata` is even populated, in the database? Maybe it's empty.
Also, what are the jsonb fields of `empdata`?

To get the actual sub-fields of `empdata`, you need the `->>` operator. eg:

### get the whole json object as text

```sql
SELECT empId, empData::text
FROM employee where empId = $1
```

### get individual attributes

```sql
SELECT empId, empData->>annual_pay as salary
FROM employee WHERE empId = $1;
```

etc...
You can also try
Have a look here: https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-query-a-postgres-jsonb-column-1433

I haven't tried these out, I'm not in front of postgres right now.

Comment: Hi yen, thank you for your response. `empdata` is populating in db and it has `json` value. When I am trying to print `empdata` in logs it prints nothing. Can we fetch whole `empdata` object from db? or need to fetch sub-fields only?

Comment: empdata is jsonb, it's not text; I don't think you can just print out. You need the text formatted values. So either use `->>` for each field you need, or you need to cast the whole object to a text type (`select empdata::text`).